# Apache Flink Kafka Stream Processing based on conditions

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Am building a wrapper library using apache-flink where I am listening(consuming) from multiple topics and I have a set of applications that want to process the messages from those topics.

Example :
I have 10 applications app1, app2, app3 ... app10 (each of them is a java library part of the same on-prem project, ie., all 10 jars are part of same .war file)
out of which only 5 are supposed to consume the messages coming to the consumer group. I am able to do filtering for 5 apps with the help of filter function.

The challenge is in the `strStream.process(executionServiceInterface)` function, where app1 provides an implementation class for `ExceucionServiceInterface` as `ExecutionServiceApp1Impl` and similary app2 provides  `ExecutionServiceApp2Impl`.

when there are multiple implementations available spring wants us to provide `@Qualifier` annotation or `@Primary` has to be marked on the implementations (ExecutionServiceApp1Impl , ExecutionServiceApp2Impl).

But I don't really want to do this. As am building a generic wrapper library that should support any no of such applications (app1, app2 etc) and all of them should be able to implement their own  implementation logic(ExecutionServiceApp1Impl , ExecutionServiceApp2Impl).

Can someone help me here ? how to solve this ?

Below is the code for reference.

```
@Autowired
private ExceucionServiceInterface executionServiceInterface;

public void init(){
    StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    FlinkKafkaConsumer011<String> consumer = createStringConsumer(topicList, kafkaAddress, kafkaGroup);
    if (consumer != null) {
        DataStream<String> strStream = environment.addSource(consumer);
        strStream.filter(filterFunctionInterface).process(executionServiceInterface);
    }
}
```

```
public FlinkKafkaConsumer011<String> createStringConsumer(List<String> listOfTopics, String kafkaAddress, String kafkaGroup) throws Exception {
        FlinkKafkaConsumer011<String> myConsumer = null;
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaAddress);
            props.setProperty("group.id", kafkaGroup);
            myConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer011<>(listOfTopics, new SimpleStringSchema(), props);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return myConsumer;
    }
```

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by using Reflection, below is the code that solved the issue.

Note : this requires me to know the list of fully qualified classNames and method names along with their parameters.

```
@Component
public class SampleJobExecutor extends ProcessFunction<String, String> {

@Autowired
MyAppProperties myAppProperties;

    @Override
    public void processElement(String inputMessage, ProcessFunction<String, String>.Context context,
            Collector<String> collector) throws Exception {
        
        String className = null;
        String methodName = null;
        try {   
            
            Map<String, List<String>> map = myAppProperties.getMapOfImplementors();
            
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(inputMessage);
            if (json != null && json.has("appName")) {
                className = map.get(json.getString("appName")).get(0);
                methodName = map.get(json.getString("appName")).get(1);
            }
            
            
            Class<?> forName = Class.forName(className);
            Object job = forName.newInstance();
            Method method = forName.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, String.class);
            method.invoke(job , inputMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```